Deploy Python Web application to Azure AppService
I'm new to Python. I'm trying to deploy Flask application to AZ AppService through VS code.
I had created AppService and generated requirements.txt file through virtual environment. When deploying to AppService through VS code I faced the error which is given below:
Warning:
Retrying(Retry(total=4,connect=None, read=None, status=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFERROR(8,'EOF occurred in violation of protocol(_ssl.c:1000)'))'
Retrying(Retry(total=3,connect=None, read=None, status=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFERROR(8,'EOF occurred in violation of protocol(_ssl.c:1000)'))'
Retrying(Retry(total=2,connect=None, read=None, status=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFERROR(8,'EOF occurred in violation of protocol(_ssl.c:1000)'))'
Retrying(Retry(total=1,connect=None, read=None, status=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFERROR(8,'EOF occurred in violation of protocol(_ssl.c:1000)'))'
Retrying(Retry(total=0,connect=None, read=None, status=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFERROR(8,'EOF occurred in violation of protocol(_ssl.c:1000)'))'
Error:
Could not install packages due to an OSError:HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org',port=443): Max retries with exceeded url....

Tried:
I had tried using Pipelines but that too got failed, so I tried using VS Code but it show deployment failed.
Expectation:
I need to deploy the Flask application to AZ AppService through VS Code and the deployment should be successful. Based on this, I need to work on next task.

Can you share the code tried so far? @user25263310

Its an hello world code

Can you share the init.py to work on the issue. @user25263310

Are you trying to run the similar one as given in MSDoc. @user25263310

Using Doc as you showed above, I dont have init.py file

Ok can you share the main code part or where the issue has been coming.  @user25263310

Still the issue was not solved for me

@user25263310 Can you share the current status and blockers/errors?

I'm using devops to deploy through app service and it is working fine .

Basically, the error SSLEOFERROR(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol(_ssl.c:1000)) comes when there is an issue with the SSL/TLS connection during deployment. Check below points to resolve it.
Need to check below:

Sometimes if you have a certifi which is not upgraded leads to this connection issue. Make sure that it is upgraded to the latest release.
Use pip install certifi --upgrade for upgrading it.

Disable the VS code app service extensions and enable it to remove any glitches or bugs. Or simply restart the VS code once and try the deployment again.

Make sure that there are no firewall connections that are blocking the deployment congestion.

If still the issue persists with the VScode deployment menthod, use Az CLI for deployment.
Deployment CLI command:  az webapp up


After checking the above, I tried deploying a flask app by activating a Python virtual environment and was able to perform all the sequel operations successfully as shown below.
py -m venv .venv
.venv\scripts\activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
flask run




Check the deployments by visiting the web app to check the status of the deployment.
Path URL: https://<Webapp>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments

